# XML Parcing Con JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Buenas estoy intentando mostrar el contenido de un XML mediante la libreria de JDOM,pero al parecer no me esta mostrando los sub-Nodos de un determinado campo de el fichero XML no se si la solucion que estoy intentando implementar pues soy bastante nuevo en esto de el parceo de documentos XML,os dejo el codigo.

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
File xmlFile = new File( "E:\\Desarollo\\AED\\workspace\\Ficheros\\libros.xml" );   
try
 {
       Document document = (Document) builder.build( xmlFile );
       Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren( "Libro" );


        for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ) {

            Element Libros = (Element) list.get(i);

            String isbn = Libros.getAttributeValue("ISBN");
            String titulo = Libros.getAttributeValue("Titulo");
            System.out.println( "Titulo: " + titulo+" "+"ISBN= "+isbn );

            List<Element> lista_campos = Libros.getChildren();

            for ( int j = 0; j < lista_campos.size(); j++ ) {

                Element campo = (Element)lista_campos.get( j );

                String Ejemplar = campo.getChildTextTrim("Ejemplar");
                System.out.println(Ejemplar);

                String Autor = campo.getChildTextTrim("Autor");
                System.out.println(Autor);


            }
        }
```

Y esto me esta dando la siguente salida en consola
[image: Salida en consola]

Como se puede observar hay ciertos nodos que me los coloca a NULL mi duda es la siguiente como consigo que me imprima todos los nodos no solo el primero, Os dejo también el archivo XML original.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo para modificar el código será bienvenida gracias de ante mano comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estas comiendo la etiqueta Ejemplares por lo que no funciona correctamente por eso:

```
Element ejemplares = Libros.getChild("Ejemplares");
List<Element> listaEjemplares = ejemplares.getChildren();

for ( int j = 0; j < listaEjemplares.size(); j++ ) {
     Element campo = (Element)listaEjemplares.get( j );
     String Ejemplar = campo.getChildTextTrim("Ejemplar");
     System.out.println(Ejemplar);
}
Element autores = Libros.getChild("Autores");
List<Element> listaAutores = autores.getChildren();

for ( int j = 0; j < listaAutores.size(); j++ ) {
     Element campo = (Element)listaAutores.get( j );
     String Autor = campo.getChildTextTrim("Autor");
     System.out.println(Autor);
}
```

Comment: Estoy observando tu codigo para ver en que difiere de el mio y lo estoy probando pero aun asi no me esta funcionando creo que no llego a entender lo que estas haciendo exactamente,veo que creas una lista separada para cada elemento,donde debo añadir tu codigo al mio para que funcione como debe?

Comment: Tu codigo va dentro de el segundo bucle segun loq ue puedo entender,probando solo me muestra los titulos y demas pero no me muestra ni los ejemplares ni los autores.

Comment: Es que si te fijas en el xml tienes una etiqueta llamada Ejemplares y dentro de ella tienes Ejemplar por ende primero debes agarrar a la etiqueta hija de Libro para poder entrar a la nieta (hija =Ejemplares y nieta = Ejemplar) lo mismo pasa con Autores y Autor